# PHP Array Operation

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array('id1','id2',...);
```

How to get `#id1,#id2,..` from the above array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = array('id1', 'id2', ...);

$ids = '#' . join(',#', $arr);

echo $ids;  // => #id1,#id2,...
```

Comment: Love it... so short, but exactly on target. +1

Comment: @Doug: Make it even shorter: `'#' . join(',#', $arr);`.

Comment: @Alix True. I always use `implode` though because it parallels `explode`. Since `split` is deprecated, it seems weird to me to use `join` and `explode` together.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. For some reason I thought that since 'split' is deprecated then so is 'join,' but I that was silly of me. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Jordan: I always use `implode()` too, I was just adding an emphasis on Doug comment. =)

Comment: Right, but I prefer join myself. It just makes more sense in my brain. "implode" seems like such a violent verb. I guess my approach to programming is a bit synaesthetic at times.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr[0];
$arr[1];
```

The code you just provided is the same as

```
$arr = array(
    0 => "id1",
    1 => "id2");
```

In order to make a list of ids in CSS

```
$string = '';
foreach($arr as $id)
{
    $string .= "#" . $id . " ";
}
```

Comment: +1 for covering both possible interpretations of an ambiguous question.

Comment: Yeah, read it wrong the first time. Thought he was asking how to access them period.

Comment: Just because he used id1 and id2 doesn't mean every ID will begin with id and end with a number, those are just examples. They could be IDs such as 'harp1', 'mem1', and 'gut2', completely irrelevant of each other.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate the array

```
foreach ($arr as $k){
  print "#".$k."\n";
}
```

each "$k" is your array items